# How do I display images side by side(e.g. 2 images in a row and then next row) contained in an array in angular 8?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular8

Below is my HTML code that I wrote and tried:

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let url of urls" class="col-md-6">
        <img [src]="url" alt="Image not found" height="250px" width="350px" (click)="imageClick(url)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: `urls` is the array conatining the array of url's for images!

Comment: What's the issue in above code?

Comment: This doesnot help me displaying the images side by side in a row.It displays vertically down one after other.

Comment: Above code will work fine assuming your screen width is more than 768px and there is enough space for two images of width 350px. 
Please check for extra padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May try using `flexbox`

```css
.img-container {
display:flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: space-evenly;
}
.img-container img{
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let url of urls" class="col-md-6 img-container”>
        <img [src]="url" alt="Image not found" height="250px" width="350px" (click)="imageClick(url)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> You can play with styles as per requirement of design

```css
.item {
  width: 100%
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 0 50%;
  /*demo*/
  border: red solid;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>



<!--your code-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let url of urls">
        <img [src]="url" alt="Image not found" height="250px" width="350px" (click)="imageClick(url)"></div>
</div>
```